# Meaning of in power

Tags: usage

I don't understand the meaning of **in power**

> China’s Communist Party celebrated its 70th anniversary **in power** with a parade on Tuesday showcasing the country’s economic growth and newest weapons.

[***Link***](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/chinas-70-year-parade-shows-economic-and-military-might/article29563252.ece)

Does it mean **the 70th anniversary of when it first got into power**?

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: It might help to interpret it as the CP *celebrating its 70th anniversary **of being** in power*. Syntactically the cited usage *could* be understood as adverbially modifying ***celebrated*** (powerfully, in a powerful style, impressively), but in practice we all know the real-world referent, so that reading can be dismissed on semantic grounds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, it basically means its been 70 years since China's communist party got into power.

Answer (score 0):

The word **power** means a couple of things, depending on how you use it. According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/power) two of the definitions of power are as follows:

> legal or official authority, capacity, or right

as well as ...

> possession of control, authority, or influence over others

In terms of your sentence, **power** here relates to political power, namely the "*legal or official authority*" of a government (in this case the Chinese Communist Party) in that they are in "*possession of control*" of China and "*have authority and influence over others*", namely the Chinese people.

Adding the word **in**, in front of the word **power** just tells to us who held (or is currently holding) that political power.